# Equivalence of two events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm reading through a book on Brownian motion, and came across a seemingly simple problem at first that's stumped me at a second glance. Given two independent standard normal random variables, why is it the case that:
$$\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{s}|Z_1| > \sqrt{1-s}|Z_2|) = \mathbb{P}\bigg\{\frac{|Z_2|}{\sqrt{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}}<\sqrt{s}\bigg\}$$
for $s\in[0,1]$.  I'm not sure where the Rayleigh variable in the denominator comes from, and the book that I am reading provides no justification for the jump. I don't find this self-evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides and rearrange and then take square root again.